# Use of conditional trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

Good day,

I have recently discovered the triggers in mysql and I find the principle great. Now, I am trying to call a stored procedure under the condition that the updated row field contains 'ee'. I thought that it is possible to have 'conditional' triggers.

```
IF (NEW.updator_trigger = 'ee')
BEGIN
CALL sp_tbl_activity_log_insert (NEW.id_component, NEW.value);
END
```

I'm getting a syntax error that I don't quite understand. Am I missing brackets or something like that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: IF (...) THEN
(...)
END IF;
Check [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Radosław, this is how I solved my problem, if it might be useful to someone :

```
BEGIN
IF (NEW.updator_trigger = 'ee') THEN
    CALL sp_tbl_activity_log_insert (NEW.id_component, NEW.value);
END IF;
END
```

Have a good day.